# I have a Raspberry PI, loaded Debian, loaded mysql, loaded RVM, trying to run Bundle install --without production

Tags: debian, ruby

Originally when I try to run "ruby server" I get this:

```
i@ruby-pi-chas1 ~/projects/sample $ ruby server
ruby: No such file or directory -- server (LoadError)
```

When I run the bundle install the system takes a long time to load, Raspberry PI so I get that.  The bundle install gets stuck at this point, I have left the system sit for hours and still just gets hung?

I tried to run the gem install libv8 as directed but it gets hung also?

Any ideas on where to look at log files or a way to determine what is going on would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I issue this command:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Screen Info:

```
Fetching gem metadata from ...........
Fetching additional metadata from ..
Resolving dependencies.........................................
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
```

...
This is where the screen is before I  out.
...

```
sing jbuilder 2.1.0
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
^C
SystemExit: exit
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
pi@ruby-pi-chas1 ~/projects/sample $
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: I am having issues trying to understand your question. What framework are you trying to use? Rails? If so, it is "rails server" not "ruby server". You do have a problem with libv8, I don't remember seeing that in my Rails installations. I will give it a check later today and comment again.

Comment: I was trying to get rails to install, I was at the point of doing a bundle install command...for gems to run? I am installing rails on debian on a raspberry pi device.

Comment: I was trying to get rails to install, I was at the point of doing a bundle install command...for gems to run? 

I am installing rails on debian on a raspberry pi device. The bundle command gets hung on loading one of the files, I was not sure if the device was running out of memory so I did a firmware update, there is also a setting for memory to run with 256m rather than 64m.  

I changed that setting to 256m but this system is still locking up?

Comment: ok I was able to figure out what was wrong by looking at this web link: http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails

There was a problem with the JavaScript dependances here is the lines that actually fixed the issue:
gem install execjs, 
sudo apt-get install nodejs

Rails requires a JavaScript runtime. Any of the following listed here will do. I installed node.js using this blog by Tom Gallacher (@tomgco). Thanks Tom!

also I followed the notes on the link above - great resource:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails